# {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"} error while running couchdb-lucene on windows

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I am running CouchDB and Couchdb-lucene on Windows Server 2019 version 1809.

I followed all steps documented on link https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene

My CouchDB local.ini file

```
[couchdb]
os_process_timeout = 60000

[external]
fti=D:/Python/python.exe "C:/couchdb-lucene-2.2.0/tools/couchdb-external-hook.py --remote-port 5986"

[httpd_db_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_external, handle_external_req, <<"fti">>}

[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:5986">>}
```

couchdb-lucene.ini file

```
[lucene]
# The output directory for Lucene indexes.
dir=indexes

# The local host name that couchdb-lucene binds to
host=localhost

# The port that couchdb-lucene binds to.
port=5986

# Timeout for requests in milliseconds.
timeout=10000

# Timeout for changes requests.
# changes_timeout=60000

# Default limit for search results
limit=25

# Allow leading wildcard?
allowLeadingWildcard=false

# couchdb server mappings

[local]
url = http://localhost:5984/
```

Curl outputs

```
C:\Users\serhato>curl http://localhost:5986/_fti
{"couchdb-lucene":"Welcome","version":"2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"}

C:\Users\serhato>curl http://localhost:5984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"3.1.1","git_sha":"ce596c65d","uuid":"cc1269d5a23b98efa74a7546ba45f1ab","features":["access-ready","partitioned","pluggable-storage-engines","reshard","scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

Design document I defined in CouchDB which aims to create full text search index for RenderedMessage field

```
{
  "_id": "_design/foo",
  "_rev": "11-8ae842420bb4e122514fea6f05fac90c",
  "fulltext": {
    "by_message": {
      "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.RenderedMessage); return ret }"
    }
  }
}
```

when I navigate to http://localhost:5984/dev-request-logs/_fti/_design/foo/by_message?q=hello

Response is

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

when I also navigate http://localhost:5984/dev-request-logs/_fti/
Response is same

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

I think there is a problem with external integration to lucene engine. So to my cruosity i try to execute python command to check if py script is running.

```
D:/Python/python.exe C:/couchdb-lucene-2.2.0/tools/couchdb-external-hook.py
```

but the result is

C:\Users\serhato>D:/Python/python.exe C:/couchdb-lucene-2.2.0/tools/couchdb-external-hook.py
File "C:\couchdb-lucene-2.2.0\tools\couchdb-external-hook.py", line 43
except Exception, e:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of search I finally got into this link

https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/issues/265

the query must be through directly Lucene not coucbdb itself. Below url returns the result

```
C:\Users\serhato>curl http://localhost:5986/localx/dev-requestlogs/_design/foo/by_message?q=hello
```

Original Documentation is very misleading as all the examples uses couchdb default port not the Lucene.

Or am I missing something ??